# Find Employees having Pending Salary

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2005

There is a table - 'EmpSalary' -  with Employee ID, Salary paid date and Salary amount. When a salary is paid for an employee, an entry will be posted in this table.
I want to find out the employees whose salary is pending (means either no salary is given or partially given) upto a given month in the current year.
The entire employees are available in 'Employee' table. I am using SQL Server 2005

```
EmpID   SalDate     Amount      AmtPending
------  -------     -------     ----------
1       3 Jan 2019  5000        0
2       4 Jan 2019  3000        500
3       4 Jan 2019  4000        0

1       4 Feb 2019  4500        500
3       4 Feb 2019  4000        0

1       3 Mar 2019  5000        0
```

Expected Result - Pending upto February

```
EmpID   Amount
------  ------
1       500
2       4000     --500 from Jan + 3500 from Feb
```

Since 3 has no pending upto Feb,no need to display 3

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. And also take a look at  [mcve].'

Comment: Also, explain why you are using SQL Server 2005, a product that has been expired for years.

Comment: It is an old system...some maintenance project

Comment: How do you know that EmpID 2 have 3500 pending from Feb.

Answer (score -1):

Do you just want `group by` and `having`?

```
select empid, sum(amtpending)
from empsalary
group by empid
having sum(amtpending) > 0;
```